# Combine partitions in GParted after removing Windows from dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, elementary

**Hello guys!**

I've just removed Windows 10 from my PC so now I am only with Ubuntu (Elementary OS).

Everything is working just fine, but now I want to expand my Linux partition to take all the space on the HDD. I am using GParted, but

[image]

I want to combine /dev/sda6 with the "new partition", please help me.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't combine partitions, you delete the old windows partition and grow the linux partition via GParted to claim all unused space. In your case, if you made a new partition to start clean, just delete it again.

Make sure that there is no data to salvage from it before the delete.

After this, you can grow the linux partition via GParted, **but not if it is mounted**. So you need to boot from a live install medium with GParted (latest Ubuntu install works fine) to accomplish this.